# What's the WWW Server/1.1?

Tags: webserver, www

I use netcraft.com query a site there shows Web server: `WWW Server/1.1`.

[image: 1]

I want to know what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WWW Server` means that a web server is running, and the `1.1` is very likely shorthand for `HTTP Version 1.1`.

In short, this result probably means that there was a web server found, and that web server is using HTTP Version 1.1.

Comment: So, there do not shows the web server's type.